# What does ’ (fancy apostrophe?) mean in PHP

Tags: php, symbols

I got this example PHP code:

```php
if ( $new_value && ’ == $old_value )
```

1. What do I call the character after `&&`
2. What does it do
3. How do I type it on my keyboard, and
4. Most importantly, what can I use in its place that is human readable and doesn't look like I'm trying to show off my knowledge of obscure code shorthand?

I don't find it here: [Reference — What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php) and since Google ignores it, and most other searches treat `’` the same as `'`(apostrophe) I'm coming up empty.

Comment: Enable error reporting https://3v4l.org/VRYMV.

Comment: @IMSoP fascinating. have an upvote for the detailed answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This character has no particular meaning in PHP, and is probably just a mistake in the code you're reading. For instance, it may have been intended as `''` (an empty string) but got messed up by some markdown-style formatting system.

Until PHP 8.0, it doesn't actually produce an error due to the combination of two slightly odd features:

- Any name that would be a valid constant name, but isn't currently defined as a constant, is treated instead as a string, as though you'd defined the constant with a value the same as the name. This feature was removed in PHP 8.0.
- Any byte that is outside of 7-bit ASCII (i.e. values 128 to 255) is allowed in a variable or constant name, even at the start. Since this character isn't in ASCII, it will be rendered in UTF-8 using a bunch of bytes that match this rule - note that PHP doesn't actually care about their meaning in UTF-8, it just sees they're non-ASCII and lets you use them wherever.

The result is that `’ == $old_value` is actually interpreted as `'’' == $old_value`, i.e. "does `$old_value` match a string containing the character `’`?"

In PHP 8.0, this interpretation is no longer allowed, and you'll get an error at runtime that the constant isn't defined. However, you can actually define this constant, and [the code will run on all PHP versions from 4.3 up to and including 8.0](https://3v4l.org/1LQvW) without any errors or warnings at all:

```php
<?php

// Define our oddly-named constant to have a value of 'hello'
define('’', 'hello');

// Compare it against a normal string variable
$foo = 'hello';

if ( ’ == $foo ) {
    echo 'It works!';
}
```

Just to be clear, this isn't particularly useful, unless you're trying to play a prank on someone, it just explains the surprising fact that this isn't a syntax error.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! Don't think it's a "mistake" just think it's sloppy old code... Probably something someone got away with once, and continued using it because it saved, what, a few keystrokes?